# Определить компьютер в сети, скорость взаимодействия с котором наибольшая

Tags: сеть, cmd

Определить компьютер в сети, скорость взаимодействия с котором
наибольшая.

```
@echo off
set /a x=9999
set y = ""
del ip.txt
arp -a | find /i "динамический" >> ip.txt
arp -a -v | find /i "недопустимый" >> ip.txt
for /f "tokens=1" %%i in (ip.txt) do (
    ping %%i > %%i.txt
    find "Cреднее" %%i.txt > _%%i.txt
    del %%i.txt
    rename _%%i.txt %%i.txt
    for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (%%i.txt) do (echo %%~a) > _%%i.txt
    del %%i.txt
    rename _%%i.txt %%i.txt
    for /f "tokens=2" %%j in (%%i.txt) do (
  if %%j lss !x! (
  set /a x=%%j
  set y =%%i
  )
  )
  )
echo %x% >> result.txt
echo %y% >> result.txt
```

Проблема возникает на стадии сравнения пинга из созданного файла с начальным заданным (x = 9999), и в результате в файл выводит заданное 9999, а %y% вообще ничего не выводит

Answer (score 1):

Скорость взаимодействия с компьютером нужно измерять при помощи передачи/скачивания файла, а не скоростью ответа ping'a. Зацените программу iperf, у нее консольный интерфейс и возможность запуска из командной строки. Она выдаст более правдоподобные результаты.

Comment: Необходимо реализовать данную задачу при помощи файла сценариев, без сторонних программ

Comment: НУ в таком случае используйте ВСЕ доступные сервисы удаленного ПК - как правило это только SMB, и обычно требуют административных прав. Либо - RDP, но там измерение скорости становится не тривиальной задачей..